# PHPUnit Integration into NetBeans 7

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I am trying to get PHPUnit working in Netbeans. I was using 3.4.9 but that refused to work and it was suggested to upgrade to the latest version. I have now upgraded to 3.5.15 and when I run it I get the following message:

```
unrecognized option --log-xml
```

I understand that this is not a valid logging option, however I do not know where this is being set or how to change it. My phpunit.xml file is:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php"  colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Personal Development">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>


    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8"
            yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I assume it gets passed when phpunit is invoked, check the command that get's execute and look if there is some configuration you can influence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to force PHPUnit to use the correct files, I had to right click on the project name, Set Configuration, Customize, PHPUnit, then specify implicitly where the bootstrap and XML Config files were.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem using XAMPP, PHPUnit 3.5 and NetBeans 7. The problem is, that NetBeans for some reason always passes the option "--log-xml" to phpunit.bat, but this option does not exist in PHPUnit 3.5 any more.

My solution was to edit the PHPUnit configuration XML file:
C:\xampp\php\PEAR\tests\MIME_Type\tests\phpunit.xml

(Note that the file path depends on the path your PEAR or PHPUnit installation is located!)

I had to append a new node, "logging":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit strict="true" colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
>
 <filter>
  <whitelist>
   <directory suffix=".php">../MIME/</directory>
  </whitelist>
 </filter>
 <logging>
  <log type="junit" target="c:/xampp/tmp/logfile.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
</phpunit>
```

After this change, NetBeans does not pass the "--log-xml" option anymore, but the "--log-junit" option, which is valid for PHPUnit 3.5. MyTests do now validate again. :-)